# C++ Semaphore Confusion?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio, semaphore

So, I'm writing a sort of oscilloscope-esque program that reads the the serial port on the computer and performs an fft on this data to convert it to the frequency spectrum. I ran into an issue though with the layout of my program which is broken up into a `SerialHandler` class (utilizing `boost::Asio`), an `FFTHandler` class, and a `main` function. The `SerialHandler` class uses the ``` boost::Asio`` async_read_some ``` function to read from the port and raise an event called `HandleOnPortReceive` which then reads the data itself.

The issue was that I couldn't find a way to pass that data from the event handler, being raised by an `io_service` object on another thread, to the `FFTHandler` class, which is on yet another thread. I was recommended to use semaphores to solve my problem, but I have next to no knowledge on semaphore.h usage, so my implementation is now rather broken and doesn't do much of anything it's supposed to.

Here's some code if that makes it a little clearer:

```
using namespace Foo;
//main function      
int main(void){
     SerialHandler serialHandler;
     FFTHandler fftHandler;

     sem_t *qSem_ptr = &qSem;

     sem_init(qSem_ptr, 1, 0);

     //create separate threads for both the io_service and the AppendIn so that neither will block the user input statement following
     serialHandler.StartConnection(tempInt, tempString); //these args are defined, but for brevity's sake, I ommitted the declaration

     t2= new boost::thread(boost::bind(&FFTHandler::AppendIn, &fftHandler, q, qSem));

    //allow the user to stop the program and avoid the problem of an infinite loop blocking the program
    char inChar = getchar();
    if (inChar) {...some logic to stop reading}
}




namespace Foo{

    boost::thread *t1;
    boost::thread *t2;
    sem_t qSem;
    std::queue<double> q;
    boost::mutex mutex_;

    class SerialHandler{
    private:
        char *rawBuffer; //array to hold incoming data
        boost::asio::io_service ioService;
        boost::asio::serial_port_ptr serialPort;
    public:

            void SerialHandler::StartConnection(int _baudRate, string _comPort){
                //some functionality to open the port that is irrelevant to the question goes here

                AsyncReadSome();  //starts the read loop

                //create thread for io_service object and let function go out of scope
                t1 = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService)); 

            }

            void SerialHandler::AsyncReadSome(){

                //there's some other stuff here for error_catching, but this is the only important part
                serialPort->async_read_some (
                            boost::asio::buffer(rawBuffer, SERIAL_PORT_READ_BUF_SIZE),
                            boost::bind(
                                    &SerialHandler::HandlePortOnReceive,
                                    this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred, q));
           }

           void SerialHandler::HandlePortOnReceive(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred, std::queue<double>& q){
                boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex_);
                 //more error checking goes here, but I've made sure they aren't returning and are not the issue

                 for (unsigned int i =0; i<bytes_transferred; i++){
                    unsigned char c = rawBuffer[i];
                    double d = (double) c;  //loop through buffer and read
                    if (c==endOfLineChar){
                    } else  //if not delimiting char, push into queue and post semaphore
                    {
                            q.push(d);
                            //cout << d  << endl;
                            sem_post(&qSem);
                            cout << q.front() << endl;
                            cout << "size is: " << q.size() << endl;
                    }
                }
                //loop back on itself and start the next read
                AsyncReadSome();

            }
    }

    class FFTHandler{
    private:
        double *in; //array to hold inputs
        fftw_complex *out; //holds outputs
        int currentIndex;
        bool filled;
        const int N;
    public:


        void AppendIn(std::queue<double> &q, sem_t &qSem){
                while(1){  //this is supposed to stop thread from exiting and going out of scope...it doesn't do that at all effectively...
                    cout << "test" << endl;
                    sem_wait(&_qSem); //wait for data...this is blocking but I don't know why
                    double d = _q.front();
                    _q.pop();
                    in[currentIndex]=d; //read queue, pop, then append in array
                    currentIndex++;
                    if (currentIndex == N){ //run FFT if full and reset index
                            currentIndex = N-overlap-1;
                            filled = true;
                            RunFFT();
                    }
                }

         }
    }

}
```

That debug line in `FFTHandler::AppendIn(..)` is indeed firing, so the thread is being created, but it's immediateley going out of scope it seems and destructing the thread, because it seems I've set up the while to respond incorrectly to the semaphore.

**TLDR**: That was a long explanation to simply say, "I don't understand semaphores but need to somehow implement them. I tried, failed, so now I'm coming here to hopefully receive help on this code from somebody more knowledgeable than me.

**UPDATE:** So after playing around with some debug statements, it seems that the issue is that the `while(1){...}` statement is indeed firing, but, the `sem_wait(&_qSem);` is causing it to block. For whatever reason it is waiting indefinitely and despite the fact that the semaphore is being posted, it continues to wait and never progress beyond that line.

Comment: I can't see anything specifically wrong with the _semaphore usage_ but I can see potential problems with threading - is `main` exiting before the thread finishes, for example? (it isn't clear from the code you've just said "...some logic to stop reading")

Comment: Why do you have the SerialHandler and the FFTHandler running on separate threads? If the intent is to pass work to another thread so that the SerialHandler can receive the next set of data, then you may want to consider the Leader/Followers pattern and have a pool of threads running the io_service. Here, each thread will  both read the data using the SerialHandler and process the data using the FFTHandler, and once done, will go back in the pool to wait on the next io event.

Comment: @aichao I have the SerialHandler io_service running on a separate thread because it loops back on itself in the handler, thus it creates an infinite loop. But, I want to be able to stop the program and unstoppable, infinite loops weren't exactly a desirable feature, so I moved it to another thread to be able to accept user input to stop this loop eventually when the user feels like it. The `FFTHandler::AppendIn(...)` function is on its own thread for a similiar reason, to not block the main thread and free up the user to be able to do things while the program runs (i.e. stop the program).

Comment: Don't use `boost::bind` with `boost::thread`, it's redundant. Just pass the arguments straight to the `boost::thread` constructor.

Comment: @imp903 Ok, I think I know what you are trying to do now. The point of my comment is that you can use the io_service as an event queue (and not just an I/O event queue) and have multiple threads handling events, including I/O events as you have now as well as "queue full for FFT" events that are then handled by FFTHandler. The separate I/O and FFT events can occur concurrently on separate threads in the sense that one thread read some more data while another is processing the previous set of data; all not blocking the main thread, which is your intent. If interested, I can post an answer.

Comment: @aichao I am curious to see how that would work, actually. That might be able to clean up my code a bit and maybe prove to be more efficient as well. If you're willing to do so, putting it in an answer would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @imp903 I have not forgotten to reply. However, as I was writing the answer, it occurred to me that I was writing a solution to your oscilloscope problem instead of answering your specific question, which would be inappropriate for SO. The solution I have is [here](https://github.com/aichao/asio-examples). Please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already using `boost::mutex` and its scoped lock type, I suggest you use `boost::condition_variable` instead of a POSIX semaphore. Otherwise you're mixing C++11-style synchronisation with POSIX synchronisation.

You lock the mutex when adding to the queue, but I don't see anything locking the mutex to read from the queue. It also looks like you're looping back to call `AsyncReadSome` while the mutex is still locked.

Pick a single form of synchronisation, and then use it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, and that did seem to clear up some confusion. I pulled the semaphores and used boost::condition_variable per your idea, which seems to work. Though it has introduced another problem (a segmentation fault), but that has not too much to do with signaling and condition variables as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

The initial value of the semaphore is 0 which is valid for this case. So it needs a sem_post for `FFTHandler::AppendIn()` to be unblocked. But I dont see the code that invokes `SerialHandler::AsyncReadSome()` for the first time for the serial port to be read and the push to happen into the queue. If you fix that part of the code, I think sem_post would happen and the FFTHandler thread would run. As the first step you can have debug prints one after the sem_wait and one inside AsyncReadSome() function, and my guess is that both wont get executed.

So, essentially you would want to ensure that 'reading' gets initiated and is kept alive as part of the main thread or a different thread.

Comment: I apologize, that's my fault, I realized I made a mistake when copying the code. I make a call to AsyncReadSome() right before creating the new thread t1. I'll update the code above. But, just in case, I did create some debug lines and those are firing so it is performing AsyncReadSome(). That being said, while playing around with your suggestion, I found something else interesting that does have to do with the semaphore, so I'll add that to the question as well.

Comment: The point you made in your update is exactly what I meant :) Thanks for keeping it posted.